# How to produce Capital hexadecimal digits with QString::arg() ? [QT]

Tags: qt, qt4, hex, qstring, qt4.6

I'm trying to create a QString which is a hexadecimal number with its letter digits in Capitals instead of small caps, how can it be done?

```
QString( " %1" ).arg( 15, 1, 16 )
```

yields `f` and I'd like `F`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By converting the string to upper case:

```
QString( " %1" ).arg( 15, 1, 16 ).toUpper();
```

This returns an uppercase string. The method used to be called upper() in qt3.

Comment: I guess that should be `toUpper()`.

Comment: Do you know of any way to convert just the output of arg()? e.g. `QString("Here is my hex byte: %1.").arg((ushort)aByte,2,16,QChar('0'))`

Comment: @M_M you have to put the arg into another QString like this:
`QString{"Here is my hex byte: 0x%1."}.arg(QString{"%1"}.arg((ushort)aByte, 2, 16, QChar{'0'}).toUpper())`

Comment: @PeterRawytsch I guess that works. It's a bit much for one line though. I was wondering if there was a more concise way. If not, I guess you're better off doing it on 2 lines: `1: QString aByte = QString( " %1" ).arg( 15, 1, 16 ); 2:QString("Here is my hex byte: %1.").arg(aByte.toUpper());`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but perhaps someone may benefit from this. If you are looking to convert a value in the range of 0 to 15 (0x0 to 0xF):

```
QString( " %1" ).arg( QChar( "0123456789ABCDEF"[ value ] ) )
```